# Change volume from float samples

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, volume

How do you increase or decrease the volume of an audio signal which is expressed in a floating point number (float).

Is it just a multiplication?

```
float volume_control(float signal, float gain) {

    return signal*gain;

}
```

How can you control that function by let's say decibels like in:

volume_control(x, 28) //should increase 28 DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, jsut multiply. If you output it, make sure to clamp the output in [0, 1] or [-1, 1] depending on your conventions.

In decibel, use:

```
return signal * pow( 10.0f, db * 0.05f );
```

See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) on decibels.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, gain is just multiplying by a factor. A gain of 1.0 makes no change to the volume (0 dB), 0.5 reduces it by a factor of 2 (-6 dB), 2.0 increases it by a factor of 2 (+6 dB).

To convert dB gain to a suitable factor which you can apply to your sample values:

```
double gain_factor = pow(10.0, gain_dB / 20.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

> volume of an audio signal which is expressed in a floating point number (float)

The first thing you have to do is find out what that float actually means.  It could be a volume control measured in db, it could be a sample that is the amount of electricity to send to a speaker at a certain time, it could be a sample that is the position of the speaker at a particular point in time.

If it is the "amplitude" of the sound wave at a particular point in time, then the above calculations are accurate.  But the fact that the sound was expressed as a float doesn't tell you anything about what the float means.